# Can't create SharePoint 2013 solution in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: 2013, visual-studio

I have a strange problem, I'm running Visual Studio 2017 on SharePoint 2013, the SharePoint 2013 template is displayed fine, but the SharePoint 2013 solution is not created!

[image]

I cannot detect anything wrong? Any idea how I can troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have installed [Office / SharePoint Template for Visual Studio 2017](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/03/11/missing-sharepoint-template-in-vs2017/) properly.

Therefore, I think the issue `"Can't create SharePoint 2013 solution in Visual Studio 2017"` is not related `Office / SharePoint Template`,

So I suggest to do the following:

- Make sure that you have opened Visual Studio 2017 **as Administrator** as I mentioned at [This task requires the application to have elevated permissions](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/06/this-task-requires-the-application-to-have-elevated-permissions/)
- If the issue still persists, try to update your Visual Studio as the following:

  - Run `Visual Studio 2017 Installer`.
  - Check your Installed Edition.
  - Click on the `Update` button.

[image]